# div displaying NaN value

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, nan

I have a function that is calculating stuff, according to inputs and selects in my html.
There are many cases that are just slightly different from each other (they differ in values, but equations/figures are the same), so in my switch, I have copy-pasted those cases. All other cases are working well, but this one not.

Here is the insight of my js (whole will be too big):

```
 function calculator() {

var val1 = parseInt($('#oblast1').val());
var sadzba = $('#demo').val();
var spotrebaVT = $('#spotVT').val();
spotrebaVT = parseInt(spotrebaVT == '' ? 0 : spotrebaVT);

var spotrebaNT = $('#spotNT').val();
spotrebaNT = parseInt(spotrebaNT == '' ? 0 : spotrebaNT);

var istic = $('#istic').val();
istic = parseInt(istic == '' ? 0 : istic);

var cenaCelkom = 0;
var cenaDist = 0;
var cenaEl = 0;

 if (val1==1){  
console.log(sadzba);
switch (sadzba) {
    case '1':
 // ... 

 else if(val1==3){

   switch (sadzba) {
    case '1':
            //BEZ DPH
            var cenaDist1 = figure;
            var cenaEl1 = figure;
            var cenaCelkom1 = cenaDist1+cenaEl1;

            cenaCelkom = Math.round(cenaCelkom1*Math.pow(10,3))/Math.pow(10,3);
            cenaDist= Math.round(cenaDist1*Math.pow(10,3))/Math.pow(10,3);
            cenaEl= Math.round(cenaEl1*Math.pow(10,3))/Math.pow(10,3);

            // here I am alerting these values and they seem ok

            alert('cenaCelkom1: '+cenaCelkom1+'  cenaCelkom:'+cenaCelkom+" Spotreba: "+spotrebaVT);
```

And here is the part where I put the values in my divs.

```
  $('#bezdph').html(cenaCelkom+' EUR');
$('#distr').html(cenaDist+' EUR');
$('#dod').html(cenaEl+' EUR');
```

Those "fugures" in my code are just a substitution for a long multiplication of constant values that I have copy-pasted and in other places they work well. Also my alert is returning right values. Why is that dvis are displaying NaN just in this case?

thank you

Comment: It doesn't look like `figure` is defined anywhere. This should actually throw a `ReferenceError`. It might have something to do with the value of `cenaCelkom1`, but I doubt we will be able to reproduce the problem with the provided code. [Learn how to **debug** JavaScript](http://www.creativebloq.com/javascript/javascript-debugging-beginners-3122820), set breakpoints, inspect variables and you should be able to figure this out on your own.

Comment: In other js file I have delared variables, like: var something=1.2365 and so on and the figure here is for example something+something1+somethin2*(something3/something4). I just putted the "figure" here, so the code is not too long. As I have mentioned the same "figures" are in other cases and it works well

Comment: Yeah, well, without knowing the actual values and computation there is little we can do. All I can tell you is that you are probably performing *some* computation (`-`, `*` or `/`) on something that cannot be converted to a number. To find out where, you have to do some more debugging. Hope that helps!

Comment: Try to modify your parseInt(value) calls to parseInt(value, 10);

Comment: like this? spotrebaVT = parseInt(spotrebaVT == '' ? 0 : spotrebaVT,10);